# exec('php path/to/script.php') 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, windows, shell, exec

I have this code, as part of a php script:

```
exec("php runScript.php --task_id {$taskId} 2>&1 ", $scriptOutput);
```

Where scriptoutput returns: 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have php in my systemvariables and when I run

`php runScript.php --task_id 1`
on the commandline it works without problems and i can use the php command for other things such as php composer.phar install.

But when my php script arrives at the rule with the exec code, it returns that php isnt recognized. The script works on Ubuntu, but not locally on my Windows environment. So perhaps it's a Windows issue.

I read a lot about environmentvariables but if that was the case i wasn't able to use php in the command line. Now it's only not working via exec.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Yes you cannot use this bash format in windows it is limited to shell of Linux and mac.

Comment: You be very clear, you are trying to invoke `exec` via a web server, is that correct?

Comment: Try using system to execute the command https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php. It worked for me.